# How perfectly fit a long text inside a circle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to perfectly fit and align a text in css and html just like on the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: http://galjot.si/css-exclusions (need to wait more for a full support)

Comment: with SVG: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextShapeInside